# Setting delegate for UIGestureRecognizer giving warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

setting delegate for UITapGesture giving warning

[image: Assigning to 'id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>_Nullable' from incompatible type 'TopPlayersViewController *const+strong']

Here is my code :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOtherPlayers = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapcollectionViewOtherPlayers:)];
tapOtherPlayers.delegate = self;
[tapOtherPlayers setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[collectionViewOtherPlayers addGestureRecognizer:tapOtherPlayers];
```

Comment: You have used UIGestureRecognizerDelegate delegate in .h file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add UIGestureRecogniserDelegate in your .h file as following :

[image]

Hope it helps..

Comment: wooo.. this worked! hell... how can i forget this!! Thank you so much man :)

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer, then mark it as CORRECT answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make "tapOtherPlayers" Variable as global and set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate delegate as bellow.

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOtherPlayers;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tapOtherPlayers = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapcollectionViewOtherPlayers:)];
    tapOtherPlayers.delegate = self;
    [tapOtherPlayers setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [collectionViewOtherPlayers addGestureRecognizer:tapOtherPlayers];
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: No this still giving the same error. I have already tried it!